# Error with PHP parameters in SQL function call

Tags: php, sql, db2

I have two PHP variables in a class that are integers ($id and $descCode).

I'm trying to get these into my SQL function call as characters (the database is looking for these to be `CHAR 2` and `CHAR 10` respectively).

For some reason, this is triggering an error:

> Use of parameter marker or NULL not valid

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
$results = array();
$results = $db->select("SELECT newCodeTest(:id,:desc) as newCode FROM testTable",
    [
        'id' => (string)$id,
        'desc' => (string)$descCode
    ]
);
```

Comment: What is `newCodeTest()` ? Where did you get this markup? Never seen anything like it.

Comment: It's a SQL function that I'm using select to call, that's how we have it set up

Comment: What does the function do? And what is the SELECT statement intended to do in general?

Comment: I think I actually fixed it with cast and the specific number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use PDO in this way.

Look at this (possible duplicate): [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter).

**Set those values as basic string**

```
$id = $pdo->quote($id);
$desc = $pdo->quote($desc);
"SELECT newCodeTest({$id},{$desc}) as newCode FROM testTable"
```

**Info about quoting:**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

**Interesting info about performance**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php#122967

Comment: I don't thing the OP is using parameters to select table or column names. Wouldn't the query just select a string literal, or actually two string literals processed by the `newCodeTest()` function?

Comment: I suppose newCodeTest(param1, param2) is his own mysql function with  2 required params. Therefore I do not understand downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it doesn't seem that table or column names are relevant here.

Comment: I'm assuming the downvote (not mine either) is because you are taking a wild shot at answering a question that you don't have enough details to answer.

Comment: There is problem with markers (:id, :desc) which are not allowed in this way. They can be used for example in where conditions, as bounds for insertin or updating data but not as params in own function.

Comment: Even if OP wanted to bind column names, escaping them is not the best solution either. Either white list them or make them constant in the code.

Comment: I actually fixed this by using cast but keeping the markers the same way. @RadimKleinpeter I didn't downvote you but I went ahead and up voted to remove the negative vote